# Flutter Navigator 2.0 avoid initial route on web

Tags: flutter, deep-linking, flutter-navigation

I'm working on a web flutter project in which I need to use Navigator 2.0 to manage custom URLs. I'm working with the official Flutter example https://github.com/flutter/samples/tree/main/navigation_and_routing which satisfies almost all my requirements. However, there's one thing taht I can't get to work, although it should be pretty simple.

In the example, you can use URIs like /book/1 and /author/1, and when opening that URL in the browser the book/author page is opened, and by clicking on the navigator back arrow you go to the main screen. In one of my use cases I need to create a route, named /album/, for example, so taht when opening /album/1 the album info is showed, but the main screen is not created below, i.e., when the back button is clicked the page does nothing or the browser returns to the previous URL. I have been trying to get it working with the [Navigator.onPopPage](https://github.com/flutter/samples/blob/main/navigation_and_routing/lib/src/screens/navigator.dart#L57) method, but it's not being called.
I would say the main page is displayed only because the [initialRoute parameter](https://github.com/flutter/samples/blob/main/navigation_and_routing/lib/src/app.dart#L40) redirects to it, but I'm not sure how I can change that only for a specific URI.

Do you have any idea of how I could change this behaviour?

Thanks a lot!